# VLC integration in Xamarin Android App

Tags: android, xamarin, integration, vlc

Any idea on creating proper Java binding project of VLC android( libVLC https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample ) so as to integrate the player in a Xamarin android app.

Answer (score 0):

Any luck with this?  I'm looking at streaming video in Xamarin.Android , would be nice to use VLC Android.

Only other decent option i found was ExoPlayer

https://github.com/martijn00/ExoPlayerXamarin

Answer (score 0):

I've added new bindings for VLC: https://github.com/martijn00/VlcXamarin

I've also updated the bindings for ExoPlayer to the latest version.